# How to output a dist from yeoman that doesnt require a grunt serve to view

Tags: javascript, html, gruntjs, minify, yeoman

I'm doing basic html/css/js project using the yeoman `generator-webapp`.  My project has nothing that would require a server to run it.  I'm using yeoman to quickly scaffold projects and minify everything. Problem being is that I must pass this work off to a designer/art director for review and they will not have a yeoman env. to view the project.  **What command can I call similar to `grunt build` that will minify all my assets but not require me to run a `grunt serve` from my built distribution folder.**

I just want anyone to beable to run the dist from clicking on the index.html

Comment: By "clicking on the index.html" do you mean run from the file system (`File://`)?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have the order confused. You use `grunt serve` while you develop, then `grunt build` (or simply, `grunt`) when you want to make a deployable version of your site. What you do with that `dist` folder is up to you.

Comment: what if you pass the code off to someone who doesnt have the yeoman env.

Comment: I encourage you to try creating a website, running `grunt`, and seeing what you get in `dist`. There's no such thing as a "Yeoman website."* Yeoman just helps you create a website, that like any other website, can be hosted/used in any way you like. *excluding the [Yeoman homepage](http://yeoman.io), of course*